# What causes visual studio to keep built dll files "open"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I edit code in visual studio and build my code using scripts (for reasons) a lot of the time. For some reason, sometimes the build will fail, giving me an error essentially telling me the dll file is in use. Closing visual studio fixes the error, implying to me that visual studio had the dll open for some reason. Why would visual studio keep dll files open, even if they are not being built?

Comment: Do you have unit tests?

Comment: Are you sure it is visual studio and not a debugger run from visual studio or something else? You can find the exact offending process using [handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)

Comment: @vc I do not have unit tests.

Comment: @Igor I'll give that a try the next time it happens